# Trouble with StructureMap and a public property I need to set

Tags: .net, structuremap

I've got an interface which i've used `StructureMap` to *Dependency Inject*.

```
public interface IFileStorageService
{
    void SaveFile(string fileName, byte[] data);
}
```

The interface doesn't care WHERE the data is saved. Be it to the memory, a file, a network resource, a satellite in space....

So, i've got two classes that implement this interface; a `test class` and a `network file storage class` :-

```
public class TestFileStorageService : IFileStorageService
{ ... etc ...}

public class NetworkFileStorageService : IFileStorageService
{
    public string NetworkUnc { get; set; }
    public void SaveFile(...);
}
```

Notice how my `NetworkFileStorageService` has a property? That class requires that value in it's implementation of the SaveFile method.

Well, i'm not sure how to define that property.

I thought i could hard code it where i define my dependency (eg. in my bootstrapper method -> `ForRequestedType<IFileStorageService>`... etc) but the kicker is .. the business logic *DEFINES* the location. It's not static.

Finally, because i use interfaces in my logic, this property is not available.

Can anyone help?

If you can, image you want to save two files

- Name: Test1.bin; location: \server1\folder1
- Name: Test2.bin; location: \server1\folder2

cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structure map assumes all constructor arguments are required and properties are optional.

There are several ways to solve this with structuremap.
You can create a factory method like this

```
x.ForRequestedType<Func<string, IFileStorageService>>()
  .TheDefault.Is.ConstructedBy(
    () =>
    NetworkUnc  =>
    {
      var args = new StructureMap.Pipeline.ExplicitArguments();
      args.SetArg("NetworkUnc", NetworkUnc );
      return StructureMap.ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IFileStorageService>(args);
    });
```

now you can create your object with

```
StructureMap.ObjectFactory
  .GetInstance<Func<string, IFileStorageService>>()("something");
```

But thats not that pretty.
Or create a config class for this class.

```
public class NetworkFileStorageServiceConfig
{
    public string NetworkUnc { get; set; }
}
```

and configure it

```
x.ForRequestedType<NetworkFileStorageServiceConfig>().TheDefault.Is.IsThis(
  new NetworkFileStorageServiceConfig { NetworkUnc  = "something" });
```

I'm sure there are many other ways to do it too.

Comment: i like -- and u probably get the necro award too :)

Answer (score 0):

if this is needed only by this implementation what about putting this in your constructor?

Comment: because I'm not sure how to define that constructor argument _at business logic time_. Remember, it's not a static value .. so how do i 'set' that in the code? I know how to define the constructor args if i was wiring up the DI with ForRequestedType<..> .. but that's not going to help.